# Show that there is no invertible continuous function $f:[0,1) \to (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is a problem I came across recently and have been trying to figure out, but I'm not having a lot of luck!

By considering the restriction of $f$ to $(0,1)$ or otherwise, show that there is no invertible continuous function $f:[0,1) \to (0,1)$.

Hint: there are bijections which map $[0,1)$ onto $(0,1)$. Can you construct one?

Comment: This is one of those classic questions, where the answer seems so, so simple, but it's kind of tricky. If you remove $0$ from $[0,1)$, then you get an invertible continuous function $f\mid_{(0,1)}:(0,1)\to (0,1)-\{f(0)\}$. Now, $(0,1)$ is connected, is $(0,1)-\{f(0)\}$ (regardless of what $f(0)$ is)?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Because this is almost certainly a duplicate. I'll try and find it.

Comment: As a tiny comment to @AlexYoucis's comment, $[0,1)$ has a distinguished point, $0$, which has the special property that removing it leaves the space connected. This is called a noncut-point. On the other hand, every point in $(0,1)$ is a cut point, that is, removing any point of it disconnects it. This property is what we exploit in his proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is that such a function has to be always increasing or always decreasing. Assume that there exist three points $a<b<c$ such that $f(a) \leq f(b)$ and $f(b) \geq f(c)$.

If either $f(a)=f(b)$ or $f(b)=f(c)$ we can conclude that the function is not injective hence cannot be invertible. Now we can assume $f(a) < f(b)$ and $f(b) > f(c)$ Then $\exists p \in [f(a),f(b)]\cap[f(c),f(b)]$.

Then by IVP $\exists m_{1},m_{2}$ such that $a<m_{1}<b$ and $b<m_{2}<c$ with $f(m_{1})=f(m_{2})=p$. Thus $f$ is not injective hence not invertible. This proves that f has to be always increasing or always decreasing.

Assume $f$ is always increasing and $f(0)=t\in (0,1)$ what maps to the rest of the values in $(0,t)$? This shows that f cannot be bijective (because it is not surjective) hence not invertible.

Comment: could you just clarify your last two lines - I'm not quite sure what you're saying

Comment: If $y\in (0,t)$ assume $\exists x$ such that $f(x)=y$ then since $f$ is always increasing, this  will require $x<0$ but that is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(0) = x \in (0,1)$. Then injectivity of $f$ implies that it is monotone, and therefore either points less than or greater than $x$ are missed.

This is in the same spirit as Alex's comment above, though the language here is more elementary. Here you have to show that injectivity + continuity implies monotonicity, there you have to show that $(0,1) \setminus f(0)$ is connected, and that continuous functions preserve connectedness. I guess the preferred answer depends on what machinery you have at your disposal, though the intuition in both cases is the same.

Answer (score -1):

a theorem states: if f:U->V is a continuous function, and A is an open set in V, then f^-1(A) is also open. the same for closed set. (c.f. Baby Rudin Chap.4 theorem 4.8.)now (0,1) is obviously open and [0,1) is obviously not open.

**Edit:Note:This answer is incorrect(see the comments).**

Comment: [0,1) is open...as a subset of itself, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: $[0, 1)$ *is* open when it's the entire space.

Comment: probably you are right... i forget about this

Comment: but why do we not treat it as a subinterval fo real line?

Comment: @Wilson Zhao, when you are considering the interval as a space in and of itself, generally it doesn't make sense to talk about a space in which it is contained. Consider the space which is the surface of a sphere $S^2$. When we are in the actual space $S^2$, then $S^2$ is open, but in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the subset $S^2$ is not open. Same goes for treating $R^{n}$ as a subspace of $R^m$ where $n < m$. For any topological space $X$, there are two sets which are always open $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: @Danikar well what if we extend the definition of this function to the entire real line? we see that the lhs limit x->1- f(x) exist becuase of monotonicity implied and f(x<0)=f(0)and f(x>1)=f(1)=lim x->1- f(x) and thus we can apply the open close argument

Comment: @WilsonZhao I do believe that argument works for extending $f$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$. But it is important to the original problem to first state that you are extending $f : [0, 1) \to (0, 1)$ to a function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and that you are applying the open close argument to this new extended function. It is worth noting that it is possible to have a continuous (non invertable) function $f : [0, 1) \to (0, 1)$. For example $f(x) = 0.5$ would be such a function even though $f^{-1}[(0, 1)] = [0, 1)$.

Comment: @Danikar makes sense. i have to read baby rudin again..